# Can a column of a data.table have more classes ?I would like to change the dates of some observations in a date column as 'out-of-bounds'

Tags: r, dataframe

Can a column of a data.table have more than one classes? For example, I have a date column (class = "Date") in my data.table and I would like to change some values of this date column: I would like to change the dates of some observations as 'out-of-bounds'. When I do this, the dates that should have been changed in 'out-of-bounds', simply become NA. I think that maybe this is due to the fact that 'out-of-bounds' is character and the dates in the column are dates and the column cannot contain a mix of classes. Do you how can I do this?

Comment: You would need to convert your whole column to a character, it can't be both character and Date at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Its not really possible, any data table column is a vector, and any vector can have only 1 type in it.
What is possible is to set specific values to be `NULL` or `NA` .